# Does there exist $a\in\mathbb N$, $b\in\mathbb Z$ that $2^na+b$ is a square for all $1\le n\le5$?

Tags: number-theory

We consider such $a\in\mathbb N$, $b\in\mathbb Z$, o numbers of the form $2^na+b$ is square to the largest possible number of values of $n=1,2,3,4,\ldots$.

It is easy to see that for $a = 60 $, $ b = -119 $ produced four squares: $2a+b=1=1^2$, $4a+b=121=11^2$, $8a+b=361=19^2$, $16a+b=841=29^2$. The next value $ 32a + b = 1801 $ square is no longer.

And now the actual questions:

a) Does there exist $a\in\mathbb N$, $b\in\mathbb Z$ that $2^na+b$  is a square for all $1\le n\le5$?

b) Does there exist $a\in\mathbb N$, $b\in\mathbb N$ that $2^na+b$  is a square for all $1\le n\le4$?

Comment: If $2a+b,4a+b,\cdots,32a+b$ are all squares, then $a$ must be divisible by $715$ (checked with Wolfram Mathematica)

Comment: Also, $a$ is (obviously) divisible by $2$. More testing shows that for every prime $p\in\{7,17,23,31,47\}$ either $a$ or $b$ must be divisible by $p$ (in these tests I checked for those properties until the $99$'th prime, which is $523$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$a = 4110224238120;
> b = 74019764836081 $$

the numbers for the item b)

[image]

[image]