# The integers $a$ and $b$ have the property for every nonnegative integer $n$ the number of $2^na +b$ is the square of an integer. Show that $a = 0$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> The integers $a$ and $b$ have the property that for every nonnegative integer $n$ the number of $2^na +b$ is the square of an integer. Show that $a = 0$.

I have been trying to show that if $2a+b$ is a perfect square then $4a+b$ or $8a+b$ isn't. Am I going the wrong way? Could you give some hints to proceed with? Do you have any ideas on how to proceed with this question?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640530/does-there-exist-a-in-mathbb-n-b-in-mathbb-z-that-2nab-is-a-square-for

Comment: @Roman83 It doesn't help.

Comment: if $2a+b$ is a perfect square then $4a+b$ and $8a+b$ can be a perfect square

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h23626p150403 http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h145117 http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146h150376_a_8

Answer (score 2):

Assume that such integer $a,b$ exists that $a \neq 0$.

Let
$$2^na+b=x_n^2$$
$$2^{n+2}a+b=y_n^2,$$
then
$$4x_n^2-y_n^2=(2x_n+y_n)(2x_n-y_n)=3b\Rightarrow2x_n+y_n\le 3b.$$
But for sufficiently large $n$ sum $2x_n+y_n$ not bounded if $a \neq 0$. Contradiction.

Thus, we have $a=0$.

**Addition:**

We can finish a little differently: since we can take a couple different pairs $(x, y)$, then the number $3b$ infinite number of ways represented as the difference of two squares. However, such natural numbers does not exist, since each number n is resolved into two factors is not more than $\sqrt n$ means.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by But for sufficiently large $n$ sum $2x+y$ not bounded if $a \neq 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: $a,b$ can be any integers, not just non-negative integers. If $b$ is negative and wlog $x,y\ge 0$, then $2x+y>3b$.

Comment: @Dhruv Why notify me...

Comment: @Roman83 So you basically mean that for some value of $n$, $2x+y$ will be bigger than $3b$? I understand the exception when $a=0$ but I still don't believe 'for sufficiently large $n$'.

Comment: As I said, this is not a fully correct answer. If $b$ were a positive integer, then $$(2x+y)(2x-y)=3b$ would imply $2x+y\le 3b$, but $b$ can be any integer. See my other comment.

Comment: @Dhruv Maybe you're right. I'm not going to delete the answer. I still think about it. Then I will edit.